# How to stub a jquery function with jasmine in an angular directive spec

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, jasmine

In an angular directive, i call `$(element).fdatepicker()`. How can i stub this `$(element).fdatepicker()` in a jasmine test for this directive?

Without stubbing it, i get the error:

```
TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating '$(element).fdatepicker({
```

My directive:

```
angular.module('admin').directive("datePicker", function($http) {
  return {
    require: "ngModel",
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
      if (!ngModelCtrl) {
        return;
      }
      $(element).fdatepicker();
      ngModelCtrl.$parsers.unshift(function(value) {
        // .. parser logic
      });
      return ngModelCtrl.$formatters.unshift(function(value) {
        // .. formatter logic
      });
    }
  };
});
```

My tests:

```
describe('datePicker directive', function() {
  beforeEach(function() {
    var element;
    module('admin');
    element = angular.element("<input ng-model='myDate' date-picker></input>");
    inject(function($rootScope, $compile) {
      var scope;
      scope = $rootScope.$new();
      $compile(element)(scope);
      scope.$digest();
    });
  });
  it('parses the value', function() {
    // ...
  });
  it('formats the value', function() {
    // ...
  });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

[jQuery plugins](https://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/) are defined on the `$.fn` object. Simply create a [jasmine spy](https://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html#section-Spies) for `fdatepicker`:

```
spyOn($.fn, 'fdatepicker').andReturn("something");
```

EDIT: The syntax for this has changed since jasmine 2.0:

```
spyOn($.fn, 'fdatepicker').and.returnValue("something");
```